# Why are so many online sources "wrong" about directional derivatives?

Tags: calculus, vector-calculus

I noticed many seemingly reputable online sources have "incorrect" description of
directional derivatives for real-valued functions in several variables.
Here, by "incorrect" I mean it disagree with the definitions in the textbooks I'm familiar with.
<s>Of course, I'm open the possibility that all the textbooks I have been using are wrong.</s> (Update: well, that's probably impossible).

For a function $f$ in $n$ variables $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$
and a unit vector $\mathbf{v}$,
almost all sources defines directional derivatives as
$$ D_{\mathbf{v}} f(\mathbf{x}) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\mathbf{x} + h \mathbf{v}) - f(\mathbf{x})}{h}. $$
So far so good.
Then many online sources state that
if the partial derivatives exist, then
$$ 
  D_{\mathbf{v}} f(\mathbf{x}) = 
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} v_1 
  + \dots +
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} v_n.
$$
This is **not true**.
At least this disagrees with all the textbook my department is using (Ron Larson).
We can also easily come up with counterexamples
where the left hand side is **undefined** while the right hand is **defined**
(Update: or even better/worse counterexamples where
one side is **nonzero** and the other side is **zero**).
Indeed, if students took the above statement literally,
then the existence of partials implies the existence of all directional derivatives,
which renders many exam questions meaningless.

Some major reputable sources that has this problem:

- [OpenSTAX Calculus volume 3](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-3/pages/4-6-directional-derivatives-and-the-gradient)
- [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectionalDerivative.html)
- [Paul's online notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/directionalderiv.aspx)

Just to name few well known ones.
These three also happen to be the first 3 search results in my Google search results
for "directional derivative".
So these are what students are most likely to see.

YouTube sources are not much better,
the 3 videos with the highest views that I can see are

- [Professor Leonard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDPp5uWSIiU&t)
- [Khan Academy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_ZRcLheNv0)
- [patricJMT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCY0XYXgYQo)

Only the last one makes this distinction explicit.

This disagreement causes real issues in classroom.
In addition to confusing students,
students very often justifies incorrect answers on exams
by referencing these sources.
It is not easy to convince students that somehow I am to be trusted
more than these reputable sources.
(no one is going to care about counterexamples).

My question is why are so many seemingly reputable sources wrong about this rather important distinction? (Update: this is an honest question. Why are they all wrong about same thing in exact same way? Carelessness in the exact same way? Yet, none of them confuse the existence of partials and differentiability. Why not be careless there too?)

Comment: I think your point "no one is going to care about counterexamples" is the most important.  One of *the* major points I try to convey in all of my courses is that mathematical truth  does not come from authority, but from logic.  I think this is actually a good opportunity to really drive that core lesson home:  it doesn't matter what all these textbooks say, if you have a counterexample then the textbook is wrong.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question that you want answered, more like a complaint that these books are wrong. Probably the reason that so many books are not more careful about this kind of thing is that real-world examples are almost all (fully) differentiable, and in real-world applications we almost always have a metric and an inner product. Multivariable calculus is basically a service course so that engineering majors can do E&M.

Comment: @BenCrowell, oops. Fixed.

Comment: @BenCrowell, typos/minor mistakes in textbooks are common, and certainly not worth our time complaining. But if three of the most popular college textbook are wrong about the exact same thing the exact same way, then it is worth understanding why.  I'm not sure I believe the engineering style smoothness assumption is the reason here. If that were true, they would say existence of partials implies smoothness. Yet none of them make that mistake.

Comment: @StevenGubkin, Great point!  I unfortunately missed those opportunity in the previous years.  I'll certainly make something good out of this this year.

Comment: I am not an expert in this area, so I would like to ask a question. Is there a condition on $f$ under which the second calculation does give the directional derivative? I ask this, because there are a lot of areas of mathematics, where I found online resources to be lacking in rigour in the sense that they pass on without proper checking what they have seen elsewhere. I suspect, this is what is happening here. The result looks reasonable, so the non-expert author passes it on without proper checking of the conditions.

Comment: @FerencBeleznay: Yeah, sorry, I probably should have stated in my question. The textbook I use (and I probably most older textbooks) just add requires $f$ to be __differentiable__. Just one word, that's it. So it is understandable if a blog post dropped this word. But is is an important condition, so I certainly don't expect online textbook writers (e.g. OpenSTAX) to miss that. And if it is just a small mistake, why would so many different sources make the exact same mistake?  (and almost nothing else)

Comment: @ssquidd Thanks, this clears this up for me. I do think that the reason is simply that the authors are not experts and not careful enough. They search their memory or the internet, they look at the first few reputable resources that comes up. The result looks reasonable. They don't think about it any more, just pass it on. I find plenty of examples like this even in printed high school texts. I guess, it started somewhere and by now it is so widespread that authors feel less and less need to question their resource.

Comment: As for convincing a student, it can also be helpful to ask them "did your resource give a proof or just stated a claim?"

Comment: Understandably (and difficult to prevent), students often do not realize how common it is for "random online sources" and beginning non-rigorous texts to over-simplify for pedagogical purposes (or because the writer is simply not sufficiently knowledgeable). However, I would hope that most any teacher is either sufficiently knowledgeable or sufficiently aware (in the sense of knowing one doesn't look in a calculus book to verify whether some subtle issue is involved) for this to be a major issue.

Answer (score 5):

It is worth noting that your definition of directional derivative allows for non-continuous functions to be differentiable (in all directions). It isn't enough to look at just straight-line paths for the definition. See page 117 of *Counterexamples* *in* *Analysis* for two interesting counterexamples. One of them is
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2 y}{x^4+y^2}, \quad f(0,0)=0$$
which is differentiable along each line through the origin, but is not continuous there. (Check it on parabolas which go through the origin. e.g. $y=\pm x^2$) Once you know that the function is actually differentiable, the limit you provide will actually give the correct answer.

To answer the direct question: because it is hard to get this stuff totally correct without losing the main point and making it look like a real analysis textbook.

Comment: The definition of directional derivative does indeed allow non-continuous functions to have directional derivatives in all directions. That's not the same as saying that the function is differentiable there though.

Comment: The issue with $f$ not being continuous is not my concern here. If that were the only issue, I wouldn't make a big deal out of it.  Even when $f$ __is continuous__ this is still clearly wrong.  And it's not some obscure fact that only analysts care about.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd agree with the second point.  It's not hard to get things like these totally correct.  All calculus textbook I own got this one right, even my old calculus for engineers textbook got it right (no offense to engineers).  So all the new authors have to do is to copy and paste, or at least paraphrase.

Comment: @Thierry Only if you are ok with not having the multivariate chain rule.

Comment: For those interested in digging into such things further, see the following sci.math posts: [Continuity in each variable vs. joint continuity](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/y2Sn5AJ2QUo/m/DmXH3ip1s6EJ) (4 June 2005) and [History of mixed partial derivatives equality](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/mNOiQfjVV7s/m/W-3JrY0iqhQJ) (9 June 2007). Also, the function $f(x,y) = \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{y^2} - \frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)$ for $xy \neq 0,$ with $f(x,0)=f(0,y)=0,$ is such that all mixed partials exist and are independent of differentiation order **(continued)**

Comment: (i.e. $\frac{{\partial}^8f}{\partial x^2 \partial y^3 \partial x \partial y^2} = \frac{{\partial}^8f}{\partial x \partial y^2 \partial x \partial y^3 \partial x} = \frac{{\partial}^8f}{\partial x^3 \partial y^5} = \frac{{\partial}^8f}{\partial y^5 \partial x^3}),$ but $f(x,y)$ is not continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0).$ See [solution to Problem 4876](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2308684) in **American Mathematical Monthly** 67 #8 (October 1960), pp. 813-814 (ASCII version in [this 21 December 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/KVsLnPngCY4/m/tnNlKZlYac0J)).

Comment: @Adam I'm not following you. Of course you can define the directional derivative this way and still have the multivariable chain rule. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Thierry You do have to be careful with what exactly you mean by "the chain rule" when you are dealing with the Gateaux derivative.  The chain rule will say $d_h(f \circ g)\big|_x = d_{d_h(g)} (f)\big|_{g(x)}$, if that makes sense.  We cannot write this as a "product of derivatives", which is what Adam might be thinking of as a "chain rule".

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess the answer is rather obvious - this relation is true if we additionally assume that the partial derivatives are continuous, in which case the function is differentiable. (The actual proof of this is deemed too technical for many such courses.) This condition is almost always met in practice, and a large fraction of courses (say, those for physicists, engineers etc.) are teaching calculus-style, computational aspect, not even bothering with rigorous definitions and proofs.

Of the sources your mention, "Paul's online notes" is clearly like that. Lots of "worked examples", and as far as I can see, it does not even give a definition of a differentiable function. It says that your formula follows from chain rule, but the conditions for the latter to be applicable are never discussed. So, I wouldn't really say it even makes a mistake here - it just doesn't discuss the class of functions to which the formula applies, and *that is true for everything there,*  not just this formula. Something similar may apply to Wolfram MathWorld.

In some cases, the condition of continuity of partial derivatives is simply forgotten. I feel it is unlikely that a properly trained mathematician would make such a mistake, so that may be a sign of the overall qualification of people involved, in which case there will be more mistakes. But I guess the popularity and "reputation" of these online sources hinges more on how well they explain things than on being correct on every detail.